# Stop node-debug from opening a new browser window

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, node-inspector, node-debugger

The command:

```
node-debug sls offline
```

opens a new browser window every time it is run.

How do we stop it from opening a new window every time? I want to reuse the existing window!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with node inspector. Take a look [here](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/721).

> Since 0.9.0 we use https://github.com/benderjs/browser-launcher2 to
>   start the browser, and make sure it's Chrome/Chromium/Opera (i.e. the
>   browsers that can properly render node inspector; we detect installed
>   browsers in the system and choose the most appropriate one; earlier we
>   used opener module which just delegated opening the browser to the OS,
>   which would open the defaul browser, which could have been e.g.
>   Firefox) and this could be the reason why the behavior has changed.
>
> browser-launcher2 actually does a bit more than just launching a
>   browser, for instance it creates a new profile for Chrome in a
>   subfolder of ~/ - this is probably the issue that @CalvinScott
>   reported (i.e. Chrome that was opened was the new profile created by
>   browser-launcher, not your original profile; you should be able to
>   open your original profile of Chrome normally)

Also, you may consider [this](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector):

> Since version 6.3, Node.js provides a buit-in DevTools-based debugger
>   which mostly deprecates Node Inspector, see e.g. [this blog post](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27#.pmqejrn8q) to get
>   started. The built-in debugger is developed directly by the
>   V8/Chromium team and provides certain advanced features (e.g.
>   long/async stack traces) that are too difficult to implement in Node
>   Inspector.